# Large Data Set | Can't Create Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with millions of rows (20+ GB) in a MySQL database.  Adding a foreign key through phpMyAdmin times out after 16 hours (current default).  The server environment is as follows:

```
OS:    Windows 2008 R2 Server

Stack: WAMP

CPU:   Xeon X3464

RAM:   8Gb
```

(Virtualized)

Is this server setup/MySQL capable of handling a data set of this size?

Comment: Two down votes; no explanation.  I'll be sure not to X next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, MySQL can handle a table that size.

innodb_buffer_pool_size should be something like 5G on your 8GB machine.  But it should not be so large that mysql swaps.

You should probably increase the timeout that is causing it to fail.

Read the details in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html -- based on exactly which version you are using and whether you are using ALGORITHM=INPLACE and whether you have other alters in the same statement.